# Select branch via URL param for Jenkins job build

Tags: jenkins

I make builds in Jenkins many times a day and I would like to automate it a little bit, but still access it through web interface.

I'm already selecting job with URL (and building this URL with very simple Alfred workflow) but I would like to also select a branch – we have many branches in repo and 90% of time I want to select `master` of `develop`

`jenkins.skypicker.com:8080/job/beta/build` works great for selecting job, but is there a way to select branch, something like `jenkins.skypicker.com:8080/job/beta/build?branch=origin/master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, theoretically, use the [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) feature to define a parameter later to be used with GIT plugin configuration. Then you should be able to use the format of url like this:

```
http://jenkins.skypicker.com:8080/job/beta/buildWithParameters?BRANCH=origin%2Fmaster
```

Be careful with the special character in the branch name though. If you can avoid it by specifying a  branch name in the form of `origin/$BRANCH` it would be safer...

Remember that in order to start the build process one must use `POST` method, not `GET` - just a side note...

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply @Łukasz-rżanek... Your answer is correct, I added new answer with few notes

Answer (score 0):

Anser by @Łukasz-rżanek is right, just adding a few notes on which I've stumbled

Set this in Job configuration:

[image]

and run it

```
#!/bin/bash
JOB_NAME="Beta"
JOB_BRANCH=""
JOB_TOKEN="TOKEN"
JENKINS_URL="http://jenkins..."
crumb=`curl "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)"`
curl -H $crumb -X POST $JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?token=$JOB_TOKEN
```